# big theta notation of harmonic series

Tags: math, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

i am want to prove that big theta notation of the harmonic series is theta(logn).
i wnat to use with integral to show that.

i'm tried to show this in the way:

```
**ln(n)=integral [1 to n] dx/x <= sum k=1 to n of 1/k <= 1 + integral [2 to n] dx/x = 1 + ln(n)**
```

in this way its not working, beacuse the "1" i cant to prove that the tight bounde of harmonic series is theta(logn).

how can i show this, and to to overcome this obstacle?
please help.

thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

One good way to get the bounds is to apply estimates to each term in the sum... either upper estimates or lower estimates.  For example:

1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + 1/6 + 1/7 + 1/8 >= 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8

Then, group the (1/4 + 1/4)=1/2 and group (1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8)=1/2 and continue.  You end up getting a sum of 1/2 "some number of times."  How many times?  Well, log_2(n) many times--I'll leave it to you to figure out why.

You can get an over-estimate in a similar manner, or perhaps an easier way is to use an integral.  Notice that 1/(x-1) >= 1/n for x in the range of [n, n+1].

So 1+1/2+1/3+1/4+...+1/n <= 1 + integral from 2 to n 1/(x-1) dx (which will make the log appear).

Comment: i tried to use inegral but look i get 1+ln(n) and its not help me prove upper bounde for harmonic series.

Comment: 1 + ln(n) <= 2*ln(n) as long as n>=e

Comment: Keep in mind that to prove the harmonic series sum of n terms is big-theta n, you only need to prove that there exist positive constants c1 and c2 so that c1*ln(n) <= HS(n) <= c2*ln(n).  The c1 can be very small (as long as it is a constant) and the c2 can be very large (as long as it is a constant).